# I can't change the value of the variable

Tags: android, kotlin

````
```
   class ApiConnect {
    private val BASE_URL = "https://www.metaweather.com"
    private var mData: Int? = null

    fun loadData(woeidID: String): String {
        lateinit var call: Call<Example>
        lateinit var service: WeatherApi
        lateinit var retrofit: Retrofit
        lateinit var cevap: String
        retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        service = retrofit.create(WeatherApi::class.java)
        call = service.queryWeather(woeidID)
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<Example> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Example>, response: Response<Example>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    response.body()?.let {
                        val detay: List<Str>? = it.consolidatedWeather
                        cevap = detay!!.get(0).theTemp.toString()
                        Log.i("woeid", "iç: " + cevap)
                        mData = 20
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Example>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.i("response", "onFailure: " + t.message)
            }

        })
        return mData.toString()
    }


}
'''
````

My mData variable is not given a value of 20. [My](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHsX6.png) loadData function returns null. How can I value mData inside the onResponse function?**
değişkenin değerini değiştiremiyorum?
*Help me please*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mData is still null by the moment when you return it. You set its value in a callback that's called sometime later, so to make it work properly you'd have to somehow wait for the callback and then return the value (why use asynchronous programming then) or return something like Future (not sure about what's there on your stack)